# ENTRYPOINT in Combination with CMD

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I have spent some time to grasp the difference between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in a dockerfile. In this case I am doing some research, so even if the Idea here might not be the best, that is more about getting how that works.

If I understood everything right, than:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
CMD ["node index.js"]
```

should result in that command:

```
/bin/bash -l -c node index.js
```

right?

What I would like to do, is create a script for the `ENTRYPOINT` which should basically look like that:

```
#entry.sh

#step 1
npm install
#step 2
npm run watch &
#step 3
compass watch &
#step n

#that line bothers me
/bin/bash -l -c $*
```

So what I would like to accomplish is: If the `CMD` changes all the »Steps 1 -n« should be executed and the resulting `CMD` should finally look like:

```
/bin/bash -l -c node index.js
```

Instead I get:

```
node index.js: entry.sh: command not found
```

Thanks for Help!

### DETAILS

```
#entry.sh
npm install
#more to come here

/bin/bash -l -c $*

#dockerfile
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "./entry.sh"]
CMD ["node index.js"]
```

## UPDATE

```
#entry.sh
#stuff from above
echo "$*"
echo "$@"

/bin/bash "$@"


#dockerfile
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "./entry.sh"]
CMD ["node", "index.js"]

/usr/bin/node: /usr/bin/node: cannot execute binary file


#Result:
node src/index.js
node src/index.js
/usr/bin/node: /usr/bin/node: cannot execute binary file
```

## UPDATE #2 -- seams to work, but I don't if that's a good idea

```
#entry.sh
#stuff from above
$@

#dockerfile
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "./entry.sh"]
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Comment: What is entry.sh?

Comment: I forgot to annotate that. Basically the lines containing the steps… I have added a comment.

Comment: Can you please post the entrypoint and cmd that produced the error?

Comment: @Robert now I get `/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument`

Comment: Yes, I did a bad suggestion

Comment: `echo $* && echo $@` in the entry.sh yields nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this and be happy:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entry.sh"]
CMD node index.js
```

entry.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#entry.sh

#step 1
npm install
#step 2
npm run watch &
#step 3
compass watch &
#step n
exec "$@"
```

Be sure of:

```
chmod +x entry.sh
```

And in Dockerfile:

```
COPY entry.sh /
```

Comment: :) That would work, indeed it is what I have tried, too. But really would like to be able to exchange the CMD

Comment: I supposed that. So now?

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen with the backround processes. I'm not at my desk know

Comment: The exec line should be `exec "$@"` in case an arg is passed with a space or some other special character.

Comment: Thanks, that seams to do it, even if the `exec` may not be needed at all…