# How to execute bash script in docker container before docker will run CMD?

Tags: docker

I have backend which I deploy from CI build to production. For CI backend needs one config and for production it needs another config. I want to copy new config in production before docker will start my backend.

Comment: ENTRYPOINT can do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631605/entrypoint-in-combination-with-cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand your question right, but maybe this can help you: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run
or this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

or this: [Execute a script before CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857897/execute-a-script-before-cmd)